# Equation Line with notes in between

Tags: formatting, equations, parnotes

Good day! How can I make an aligned equal sign even though I have notes in between the two equation lines? For example:

```
a+b=c

(some notes....)

c+d=c+(a+b)
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\intertext` from `amsmath` or `\shortintertext` from `mathtools`.

First `\shortintertext`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

  \begin{align}
    a + b &= c \\
    \shortintertext{\lipsum*[1]}
    c + d &= c + (a + b )
  \end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

and then `\intertext`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

  \begin{align}
    a + b &= c \\
    \intertext{\lipsum*[1]}
    c + d &= c + (a + b )
  \end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see the difference between the two approaches is the vertical space between equations and the inter text. It is smaller in `\shortintertext`.

Note: If your inter text is occupying space, you may want to add `\allowdisplaybreaks` additionally to break the `align` contents across pages.